# email validation emissions

Tags: regex

```
(([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)(\s*;\s|\s*,\s*|\s*$))
```

I have this regex which validates email

I'm using http://www.regextester.com/ to test it. So it works

```
sadas@asd.com; asdas@c.com; asdasda@casc.com; asjdas@asc.com, asdas@asd.com
```

but if client will write that

```
asjdas@asc.com,asdas@asd.com
```

It says that it's false. How can I do that?

Comment: This regex should not work as expected as the `-` must be at the very beginning or the very end of a character class to be matched literally (you're using `[a-zA-Z0-9_-.]`). Where did you find this regex? It seems to allow IPv4 domains (which is valid), but do you really need it? I'm pretty sure we could find a less complex regex that would still cover your needs.

Comment: What do you mean by *it says it's false*? It [works for me](https://regex101.com/r/IgLQN3/1)

Comment: @ThomasAyoub It doesn't work for you - match 6 in your example is "``asjdas@asc.com,asdas@asd.com `" and none of the sub-matches are a valid email address.

Comment: For instance, could [this one](https://www.debuggex.com/r/c-mrnoSF2zncCLIj) suit your needs?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what you need to do is, escape all the dots (`.`) by putting a backslash (`\`) before them *(as you're matching a literal dot, not [any character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html))*. So, the following *regex* would work :

```
(([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@(([[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(]?)(\s*;\s|\s*,\s*|\s*$))
```

[**DEMO**](https://regex101.com/r/9DkWKN/2)

Answer (score 0):

The reason this isn't working as you expect is that you've not escaped the `.` in the domain capture correctly.

By default `.` means "any character", where as `\.` means "the period character".

As it stands `asjdas@asc.com,asdas@asd.com` is matching as:

1. Anything up to the @ (with some caveats - `[a-zA-Z0-9_-.]+` should really be `[a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+` or move the dash to the beginning `[-a-zA-Z0-9_\.]+` so it's not treated as a range).
2. The @
3. Anything in a-z, A-Z, 0-9 or dash 1 or more times, followed by any character, 1 or more times - this is where the comma is picked up: `([a-zA-Z0-9-]+.)+`
4. Anything in a-z, A-Z between 2 and four times.
5. Spaces or end of line.

So the `,` and the second `@` all push this into the 3 item there.

That said, as others have mentioned, this is a fairly odd regex for capturing the emails from the string - and leaves a number of valid emails out of the group - for example TLDs can now be any length (`.museum` and `.aero` being two I've come across, there are [plenty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains#ICANN-era_generic_top-level_domains) [more](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains#Brand_top-level_domains)), and `'` is now quite common in the name part of email addresses.

The [following regex](https://regex101.com/r/LFGa0k/2) will grab all the email addresses, and just the email addresses from string:

```
([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+@(?:(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3})|(?:[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.+[a-zA-Z]{2,})))
```

This will ignore the spaces, handle generic and brand TLDs, and also offer limited support for IP based emails (neb@123.123.123 for example) but it will still fail for valid emails (i.e. those with apostrophes, plus signs, etc) and for invalid IPs (any octet over 256).